# Scheduled Task Execute and argument parameters

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

How should I execute batch file when creating new scheduled task action. Here is my example:`New-ScheduledTaskAction –Execute "cmd.exe" -Argument "c:\script\script.cmd;quit";`

Answer (score 0):

Execute parameter actually can be call without an argument. Corrected statement should look like this`New-ScheduledTaskAction –Execute "c:\script\script.cmd";`